# Header graphics and logo

Tags: discussion, design

There is a long time since Emacs.SE went out of beta. When will there be header graphics for the site and a logo like the other SE sites?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It used to be that sites graduated from beta at the flip of a switch, but [this is now a more gradual process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation). Emacs.SE now has no “beta” in its name, has had moderator elections, has community ads, but has not yet reached the last two steps: a distinct design and [increased reputation requirements for privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

[Computer Science graduated in September 2015](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/congratulations-computer-science-is-graduating) and [its designed launched on February 1st](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/new-site-design). [Software Recommendations also graduated in September 2015](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating) and [design work is starting now](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2480/design-ideas-for-this-site-again). There was a pretty big wave of graduations around that time as [the rules changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september). We [graduated two months later](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/congratulations-emacs-is-graduating) so I expect we'll get a design in a few months or so, once the backlog of the September 2015 wave has been processed.

Comment: I didn't know that. :)

Comment: We've got about four sites that are getting a new design in March/early April. After those launch, Emacs is second in the queue. Shouldn't be too long.

Comment: I would recommend at least the "E" logo from the [GNU site](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/images/emacs.png) if only for the interim. Of course I have no idea if it's worth the effort if it will be redesigned in a few months anyway.