# Why does emacs.stackexchange.com does not have a logo like superuser.com?

Tags: discussion

Actually there are two questions for discussion:

1. Why there are stack exchange sites with names like superuser.com and stackoverflow.com, whereas emacs forum has emacs.stackexchange.com - rather than having unique name? Ease of managing ?
2. Why can we not put up a logo for this emacs.stackexchange.com when there are dedicated logos for superuser.com and stackoverflow.com.

I do understand that the above question may apply to most stackexchange sites, I would want to know if there is any specific reason for this.

**Most important**: If this is off-topic here - then - where should I post this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites go through a number of stages. First, they are [defined](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76571?phase=definition) through example questions, and users [commit](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76571?phase=commitment) to participate in building the site. This happens on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#get-involved). Then the site is actually created, spends a few days in private beta and then a few months to a few years in public beta.

During the beta phase, the site is “on probation”; all Stack Exchange sites in beta have the same visual appearance.

When the site reaches a certain threshold of traffic, it “graduates”, indicating that the site is here to stay and isn't likely to undergo major changes in scope and culture. [We graduated last November](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/congratulations-emacs-is-graduating). The final stage after graduation is getting a distinctive design; for a long time it used to happen at the same time as graduation, but these days [it's a gradual process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation).

As it happens, [we are about to get a distinctive look](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/community-site-design-ideas-input-needed).

Stack Exchange sites don't normally have a distinctive *name*, just “<Topic> Stack Exchange”. Stack Overflow came first (Stack Exchange got its name as a generalization of Stack Overflow); then came Server Fault and Super User; then the “Stack Exchange 2.0” process which allowed other sites to be created. It was [originally planned](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) that each site would get a fancy name, but quickly [this decision was overturned](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/). So we're getting a logo, but we'll keep being called “Emacs Stack Exchange”.